# F# Windows Forms game loop

Tags: f#

I want to make game loop in F# but i have problem with that.

```
let rec gameLoop (gamePanel:Panel) =  async {
    (*redraw gemaPanel *)
    lock gamePanel ( fun() -> 
      let graphics = gamePanel.CreateGraphics();
      let rectangle = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(100, 100, 200, 200);
      graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, rectangle);
    ) 
    return! gameLoop (gamePanel:Panel)
    }

let startGame (p:Panel) (p1:Panel) = hide p; Async.StartAsTask(gameLoop p1);()
```

If i add async this loop wont execute. If i will make this loop sync it will run forever.

What i want, to have loop which will be working all time in second thread and and will redraw game every 30ms and handle keyevents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`Async.RunSynchronously`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370262.aspx) in `startGame` to actually kick off the async:

```
let startGame (p:Panel) (p1:Panel) = hide p; Async.RunSynchronously (gameLoop p1)
```

Comment: ok thx. I used Async.StartAsTask because i had deadlock with run synchronously.

Comment: Make sense - I assumed incorrectly that you wanted to wait for it to finish in `startGame`.